# What authentication is "authenticated users" referencing on a file server - local or remote?

Tags: windows, permissions, samba, authentication

Whenever I look up the permissions description for "Authenticated users" I get something like "any user who has logged on".

A non-domain Windows user accessing a Samba file server which has local usernames set up, will have **two different authentication tokens/credentials in use** - the logon they used for Windows and the logon they added or saved in Windows' "Credential Manager" for the Samba share.

A user who has run something as administrator might have more than two in simultaneous use - their own, the administrator account (with/without linked tokens in Windows) and Samba.

So, which exactly is it that's checked, when a file share/shared folder has a permission set on it: *"Authenticated User: [something]"*?

- Is it testing for a valid logon to Windows, or to the file server?
- Alternatively, which credentials are being tested as pass/fail - their Windows credentials (evaluated by Windows) or their Samba credentials (evaluated by Samba)?
- From a security point of view, if I set *"Authenticated Users = Full"*, am I giving permission to anyone who can access the Windows Client, or anyone who has a valid account with share access defined in Samba?

It seems ambiguous and I can't find a clear-cut answer on the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a non domain environment Authentication is always referring to the local machine. So "Authenticated User" is always from the view of the samba service.
If you try to access the share without a user name/password, you are treated as a guest (non authenticated) if you provide a correct user name/password you will be treated as an authenticated user.

This has nothing to do with the Windows authentication on the client side. I cant say what happens if the user name and password are the same on both sides, but in general you have to authenticate another time on the remote host. Especially as some Service like Kerberos is missing, who could authenticate you without sending over your user name/password to the remote side.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what was missing. Just to confirm, that means assigning a permission to Authenticated Users means "anyone who logs in on Samba with any account at all", or with some subset of the Samba accounts? (What I'm checking is, suppose 3 users are defined that Samba can auth locally on the server, but only 2 of them have explicit access to the share, will all 3 be AU's or just the 2?)

Comment: Authenticated user means ANY user (on that system/Domain/ect...) with a valid password. So all 3 will have access after they authenticate against the Server at one point in time.